# Codeigniter : Session can't be deleted on new server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I'm a new user of Codeigniter. I've developped a website with the Session system of Codeigniter : a user can create an account or navigate freely in a 'visitor' session.
Everything works fine on the tests server.
When I put the site on the production server, I can't delete the sessions no more with this code :

```
public function logout(){
     $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
     $this->session->sess_destroy();
     redirect('lobby','refresh');
}
```

The server is not on the same domain, machine or php version than the test version and I can't access it because the client doesn't allow me, so I can't really debug it or reproduct the issues.

The rest of the site works fine.

I did a full day of research but I couldn't find an answer to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sess_destroy()` changes the expiration time of the cookie to a negative time, so it disappears on the next refresh.
Try reloading the page, you’ll see it go away.

Also What do you have in your config file?

Set it like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: the redirect("refresh") doesn't solve this issue ?
My config file looks like this, I just don't use the database to store them.
Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to use the database anyway. or don't you use a database at all?

Comment: I use one for the user data. I will try to set it up.

Comment: It works as usual on the tests server but like I said I can't reproduce the bug on my end.
I will send a version to the client for him to test but it's going to take some time